# Excel Macro: (1) Code below doesn't work (2) How do i make a macro run real time on any sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Let me explain the problem i am trying to solve using the macro below. There's a template sheet, where i would fill in Column D. If the value of D42(Which is calculated based on inputs earlier) is < D43(A fixed value), I would like Columns E-P to remain hidden. If D42 > D43, i would like columns E-P to show up (which would require to be filled up). My code below is not working - It seems that Number_1 & Number_2 are both being assigned 0.

The second issue i am trying to solve is that I would copy this template sheet to another sheet (Let's call it XYZ) and run it there - I thought that using ActiveSheet would solve it, but doesn't seem to work. Ideally, I would like it if the macro could be running real time (Hence, no button to press to enable the macro) - No idea how to tackle this problem

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Select

Columns("E:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Dim Number_1 As Integer
Dim Number_2 As Integer

Number_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("D42").Value
Number_2 = ActiveSheet.Range("D43").Value

If Number_1 - Number_2 > 0 Then

Columns("E:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

Else

Columns("E:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put below code in with the sheet, not in module

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "D42" Then

        Dim Number_1 As Integer
        Dim Number_2 As Integer

        Number_1 = Range("D42").Value
        Number_2 = Range("D43").Value

        If Number_1 - Number_2 > 0 Then
            Columns("E:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Else
            Columns("E:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I'm not sure about you means copy the sheet to another.

If you copy the entire sheet to another workbook, above code will follow too.
Because it's attached with worksheet.

Hope this help !

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do i have to call this sub again elsewhere? I followed what you said, and added it into the sheet only. However, it doesn't seem to be working. What i meant by copying sheets is that: This is the "template" sheet, and hence, i would be copying the template sheet to a new sheet, and renaming it. Hence, i was hoping that the macro would follow as well.

Comment: Worksheet_Change will be trigger when there have changes on cells in that sheet. The only thing u need to handle is the target, because u only it trigger when specific cells changed. If you duplicate the whole sheet then rename it, the code will follow, but be careful on your reference.